# How to set image and paragraph in the middle in table row / Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I made a table using material UI. I added images and paragraph in the same row. The problem is that both of them do not align in the same height.
They should be shown in the middle of row.

Current view is like below.
The height of Logo of master card and 'Master card' do not match..

[image]

Here is my code for table.

```
 <TableRow className="tableRow">
  <TableRowColumn className="tableOne">{this.props.payment=="PayPal"? 
  <div className="failSample"> <img src={Fail} alt="Fail" className="Fail"/></div> : <div className="checkSample"><img src={Check} alt="Check" className="Check"/></div> }</TableRowColumn>
  <TableRowColumn className="tableTwo">{this.props.date}
  </TableRowColumn>
  <TableRowColumn className="tableThree">{this.props.payment=="Visa" ? <div><div className="visaSample"><img src={Visa} alt="Visa" className="Visa"/></div> </div>:  (this.props.payment=="PayPal" ?   <div className="paypalSample"><img src={Paypal} alt="Paypal" className="Master"/></div> :  <div className="masterSample"> <img src={Master} alt="Master" className="Master"/></div>)}          
     &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;  {this.props.payment}</TableRowColumn>
  <TableRowColumn className="tableFour">{this.props.narrative}</TableRowColumn>
  <TableRowColumn className="tableFive">{this.props.amount}</TableRowColumn>
  <TableRowColumn className="tableSix"><div className="dotmenuSample"><img src={Dotmenu} alt="Dotmenu" className="Dotmenu" onClick={this.handleTouchTap} /> </div></TableRowColumn>
```

CSS

```
.Master, .Visa, .Paypal {
height: auto;
width: 100%; 
float: left;
}

.visaSample {
 padding-top: 40px;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 display: table-cell;
 }

.masterSample {
 padding-top: 20px;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 }

.paypalSample {
 padding-top: 20px;
 height: 30px;
 width: 20px;
 }
```

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` is what you need http://jsbin.com/xuzerapimo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Weird, I don't understand why the alts are being displayed... Specific to reactjs or material?

Comment: I removed ``` <div className="failSample">``` and then vertical-align worked. I tried it with ```<div className="failSample">``` then I didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `flexbox` will solve your problem

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-container > div {
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>img</div>
  <div>text</div>
</div>
```

Try this inside your `<TableRowColumn`